# It seems that task0_cardinal.pyc is not found in current directory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm currently working on a project which needs to install ubuntu and run some python test files. I installed ubuntu and python. But when I run the command from terminal, I keep getting the error "It seems that task0_cardinal.pyc is not found in current directory!"

Code link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GxfywcZ1IYWxHzQVK_JZ-qr83rPWz0OL?usp=sharing

please help me in this

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to your code, please edit your post and type it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.